# wxpython setsizer

Tags: wxpython

The panel1 in page1 of the Notebook is defined with Size(400,100)..I don't want the Sizer to resize my panel..

test.py

```
import random
import wx

########################################################################
class TabPanel1(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
        self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))

    panel1 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
    panel1.SetBackgroundColour('brown')

    panel1gs = wx.GridSizer(2,2,1,2)

    panel1gs.AddMany( [ (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='FirstLabel'),0,wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='SecondLabel'),0,wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='ThirdLabel'),0,wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.StaticText(panel1,label='FourthLabel'),0,wx.EXPAND)
            ] )



    panel1.SetSizer(panel1gs)

    panel2 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
    panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5042')

    panel3 = wx.Panel(self,size=(400,100))
    panel3.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5042')

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    sizer.Add(panel1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    sizer.Add(panel2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    sizer.Add(panel3, 0, wx.ALL, 5)


        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class TabPanel2(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
        self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Notebook Tutorial",
                          size=(800,600)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        tabOne = TabPanel1(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabOne, "Tab 1")

        tabTwo = TabPanel2(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabTwo, "Tab 2")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways a sizer can change the size of an item inside it.

First is the [`wx.EXPAND` flag](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.SizerFlags-class.html#Expand) which "will cause the item to be expanded to fill as much space as it is given by the sizer." You're using this flag but you don't want this behaviour, so you should remove them.

Second, `wx.BoxSizer`s can resize objects using the `proportion` argument in the [`Add()` and `AddMany()` methods](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html#Add). [`wx.BoxSizer`'s documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.BoxSizer-class.html) states "

> [objects in the sizer] can grow in both directions (height and width) [...] This is determined by the proportion parameter give to items when they are added to the sizer. It is interpreted as a weight factor, i.e. it can be zero, **indicating that the window may not be resized at all**, or above zero.

(Emphasis added)

In your case, you are already setting the proportion to 0 and you aren't even using a `wx.BoxSizer` so this isn't an issue for you, but it's something to keep in mind in the future.

Comment: I removed the EXPAND but still the panel resizes to the Grid size..I want to maintain the panel1a size to (400,400)

Comment: @user1050619 I don't see a `panel1a`, only `panel1`

Comment: TabPanel1 contains three panel- panel1,panel2,panel3